# '-[UITextField date]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89277121c0'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm learning iOS development on Xcode 8.3.3 and iOS 10.3 using Swift 3. I'm trying to create an account creation form with a field that shows a UIDatePicker when the user performs an on touchup on the date of birth UITextField:

```
    @IBAction func showDatePicker(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -16, to: Date())
    dateOfBirth.inputView = datePicker
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}

@objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ picker: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
    dateOfBirth.text = dateFormatter.string(from: picker.date)
}
```

When I execute the above, I get the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField date]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89277121c0'
```

To me it looks like its trying to inject the UITextField 'sender' value into the datePickerValueChanged field, which is supposed to take a value of type UIDatePicker, thus causing the error. I tried to change it to where I explicitly passed the datePicker object to the datePickerValueChanged method:

```
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.datePickerValueChanged(datePicker)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

but Xcode then gives me an error:

```
Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer
```

My function has the @objc in front of it, so I'm confused why its not allowing that.

So, my ultimate question is: **How do I make sure the value passed to datePickerValueChanged is of type UIDatePicker, i.e., the *datePicker* object?**

Comment: Have you tried cleaning or rebuilding the project?

Comment: Does this error happen when the date picker first appears, or when you select a date in the picker?

Comment: I tried cleaning but it still fails. Also, this happens before the date picker is even shown.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just built a test project, and your code is working fine (see below). Are you sure the function datePickerValueChanged is in the same class? CreateAnAccountPage?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
var dateOfBirth:UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dateOfBirth = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 150, height: 75))
    dateOfBirth.borderStyle  = .line
    view.addSubview(dateOfBirth)
    self.showDatePicker(dateOfBirth)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

 func showDatePicker(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -16, to: Date())
    dateOfBirth.inputView = datePicker
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    view.addSubview(datePicker)
}

@objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ picker: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
    dateOfBirth.text = dateFormatter.string(from: picker.date)
}
}
```

Comment: And the original `#selector(self.datePickerValueChanged)` is fine too. This answer doesn't change anything.

Comment: When I try that it gives me the following error: Type 'CreateAnAccountPage' has no member 'datePickerValueChanged(picker:)'

Answer (score -1):

try:-

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```